# Hive with HBase (both Kerberos) java.net.SocketTimeoutException .. on table 'hbase:meta'

Tags: hive, hbase

### Error

Receiving Timeout errors when trying to query **HBase** from **Hive** using `HBaseStorageHandler`.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=68199: row 'phoenix_test310,,' 
         on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hbase-master.example.com,16020,1583728693297, seqNum=0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:64)
    ... 3 more
```

I tried to follow what documentation I could and have some `hbase` configuraiton options added to `hive-site.xml` based on this Cloudera [link](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_sg_hive_query_secure_hbase.html)

### Environment:

- Hadoop 2.9.2
- HBase 1.5
- Hive 2.3.6
- Zookeeper 3.5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the Cloudera link should be ignored, **Hive** detects the presence of **HBase** through environment variables and then automatically reads the `hbase-site.xml` configuration settings.
There is no need to duplicate HBase settings within `hive-site.xml`

### Configuring Hive for HBase

Modify your `hive-env.sh` as folllows:

```sh
# replace <hbase-install> with your installation path /etc/hbase for example
export HBASE_BIN="<hbase-install>/bin/hbase"
export HBASE_CONF_DIR="<hbase-install>/conf"
```

Separately you should ensure `HADOOP_*` environment variables are set as well in `hive-env.sh`,
and that the hbase lib directory is added to `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this error,by adding this property  hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period=600000

hbase 1.2

https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/admin_hbase_scanner_heartbeat.html#concept_xsl_dz1_jt